# Using a slash in the beginning of the role makes any different?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Assume this route please:

```
Route::post('/role/make', 'roleController@make_role')->name('make_role');
```

As you see, there is a `/` in the beginning of route path. The interesting part is when I remove that `/`, still it works as expected.

So is there any different between route above and this?

```
Route::post('role/make', 'roleController@make_role')->name('make_role');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably run `php artisan route:list` to confirm that it makes absolutely no difference in the resulting route in the routes lookup table, but if in doubt this is the source code that adds a route in 5.3. At some point the router calls `prefix` method on the [`Router`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L509) which does:

```
return trim(
        trim($this->getLastGroupPrefix(), '/')
        .'/'
        .trim($uri, '/'), 
 '/') ?: '/';
```

That is to say it will trim both the URI and prefix to remove the `/` and then trim the result and do the same.

I don't think this has changed in other versions.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between the two routes, the one that starts with slash and the one that doesn't. They make the same route.
It is just up to your perspective which you prefer how to write your routes.